# No provider for ConnectionBackend while inheriting from Http

Tags: inheritance, angular, angular2-http

I am trying to make a wrapper around built in Http service in angular 2 to have a possibility to add custom behaviour (headers, parameters etc.)

So I created a usual class (not a service) and inherit it from Http.
[Class definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaWkg.png)

```js
import {
  Http,
  ConnectionBackend,
  RequestOptions,
  RequestOptionsArgs,
  Headers
} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {tamamApiUrl} from '../constants';
import {CustomQueryEncoder} from './CustomQueryEncoder';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

export class BaseHttp extends Http {
  protected applicationDataService;
  protected baseUrl: string = tamamApiUrl;
  protected encoder: CustomQueryEncoder;

  constructor(backend:ConnectionBackend,
              defaultOptions: RequestOptions, applicationDataService: any) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
    this.applicationDataService = applicationDataService;
  }


  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
    this.addDefaultOptions(options);
    return super.get(url, options);
  }

  post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
    this.addDefaultOptions(options);
    this.addDefaultPostOptions(options);
    return super.post(url, body, options);
  }

  private addDefaultOptions(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs {
    if (options == null) {
      options = new RequestOptions();
    }
    if (options.headers == null) {
      options.headers = new Headers();
    }
    const applicationData = this.applicationDataService.getApplicationData();

    if (applicationData.applicationKey) {
      options.headers.append('application-id', applicationData.applicationKey);
    }

    if (applicationData.secretKey) {
      options.headers.append('secret-key', applicationData.secretKey);
    }

    if (applicationData.userToken) {
      options.headers.append('user-token', applicationData.userToken);
    }

    return options;
  }

  private addDefaultPostOptions(options): void {
    options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  }

  /*private requestInterceptor(): void {
    this.loaderService.showPreloader();
  }


  private responseInterceptor(): void {
    this.loaderService.hidePreloader();
  }*/
}
```

Than I Created a service which inherited from this class so that I can inject it later and use for my purposes.

```js
import { Headers, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import {tamamRootUrl} from '../constants';
import {BaseHttp} from '../api/BaseHttp';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ConnectionBackend,
  RequestOptions,
} from '@angular/http';
import {ApplicationService} from './ApplicationService';

@Injectable()
export class InspectionHttpService extends BaseHttp{

  protected baseUrl: string = tamamRootUrl;
  protected params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend,
              defaultOptions: RequestOptions, protected applicationService: ApplicationService) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions, applicationService);
  }

  getRootUrl() {
    return this.baseUrl;
  }
}
```

[Service definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ62K.png)

After I try to inject created service in component I receive an error:

**error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./VehiclesListComponent class VehiclesListComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for ConnectionBackend!**

I tried to search solution using stack-overflow but it see,s that HtpModule should already have all necessary for a proper work.

Could anyone help me? Where is the problem?

Comment: Also I've used this link as an example of inheritance from Http: https://blog.tomasandtomas.com/angular-2-http-interceptors-7e2d74b7f14e#.pkvaxteru

Comment: Please add the code as text to the question instead of linking to screenshots.

Comment: It is formatting very strange, but I will try.

Comment: Just select the code and press the `{}` button in the editor toolbar (or use any other way to make each code line start with at least 4 spaces)

Comment: Much better, but it was the wrong button. Snippets `[<>]` are only for code that can actually be executed inside the question, `[{}]` is for code that is not runnable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't just add it to the providers like this

```
providers: [ ApplicationService, InspectionHttpService ]
```

If you do, then Angular will try to create it, and it won't find a provider for `ConnectionBackend`

You need to use a factory, where you can just pass the `XHRBackend` (which implements `ConnectionBackend`)

```
imports: [HttpModule],
providers: [
  ApplicationService,
  {
    provide: InspectionHttpService,
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, ApplicationService],
    useFactory: (backend, options, aplicationService) => {
      return new InspectionHttpService(backend, options, applicationService);
    }
  }
]
```

With this, you can inject it as `InspectionHttpService`.

```
constructor(private http: InspectionHttpService) {}
```

If you want to be able to inject it as `Http`, then you need to change the `provide` to `Http` instead of `InspectionHttpService`. But this overrides any ability to use the regular `Http` if you ever need it.

#### UPDATE

In some environments, it's possible you may get an error with the above code. I forgot the exact error message, but it will give you a proposed solution of extracting the factory function, i.e.

```
export function httpFactory(backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions,
                            service: ApplicationService) {
  return new InspectionHttpService(backend, options, service);
}

useFactory: httpFactory
```

From what I remember, I think the error has something to do with AoT

Comment: Man, you are fantastic! Yo've saved my time. But still how could I know this? I think we still need better documentation or I've lost something while learning DI in angular2. Thank you a lot for a such quick response! Have a nice day, hope you're doing well)

Comment: I get an error - "No Provider for XHRBackend" - thoughts?

Comment: @Kudoz You still need to import the `HttpModlule`

Comment: Its imported... I think the issue is somehow related to when I'm importing my extended HTTP class.  I'm providing it within bootstrap - seems to work if I provide it as part of an ngModule.

Answer (score 0):

When extending the Http service, you have to inject backend and options for the parent class:

```html
@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptor extends Http {
  constructor(
    backend: XHRBackend,
    options: RequestOptions,
    ...
  ) {
    super(backend, options);
  }
  ...
}
```

This way you don't have to use a factory because Angular will figure the injection on its own.