# Angular 2 custom http service throws Error: No provider for XHRBackend

Tags: angular

I wanted to create my own http service so that I could use it like an http interceptor but I get a very long error that starts with: `EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for XHRBackend!`

http.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, XHRBackend, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Request, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class HttpService extends Http {
    constructor(backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
        console.log('HttpService constructor');
        super(backend, options);
    }

    request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        console.log('HttpService request');
        return super.request(url, options);
    }    
}

export const HTTP_SERVICE = {
    provide: HttpService,
    useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) => {
        return new HttpService(backend, options);
    },
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
};
```

And then I add it in app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { HTTP_SERVICE } from './shared/http/http.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthService,
        HTTP_SERVICE
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But it does not work when I inject it into a constructor in a component. I get the error mentioned.

I also read that I could do:

```
{ provide: Http, useClass: HttpService}
```

from this blog: http://www.adonespitogo.com/articles/angular-2-extending-http-provider/

But this also does not work. Here I get no error, but nothing is different. I get no output to console as I expect from the code.

I also tried to just add `HttpService` as it is in the providers array, still got that error.

Comment: You could just add `HttpModule` to the `imports` to get the providers it already defines. Then you wouldn't need `HTTP_SERVICE` and *could* just use the simple provider from the blog.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No provider for ConnectionBackend while inheriting from Http](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40507670/no-provider-for-connectionbackend-while-inheriting-from-http)

Comment: I have the same issue but no solution, did you find any ?

Comment: adding httpModule in imports will solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Mukul Jayaprakash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1320325/mukul-jayaprakash) stated, adding `httpModule` in your `imports` will solve this issue.