# What's the right way to GET file ignoring cache in Angular2 http service?

Tags: jquery, ajax, angular

I am constructing an NG2 app with app settings stored in appSettings.json. At startup, the app will download the file through http.get. By default, the Web browsers will cache the json file, and I don't want this to happen. I know in jQuery AJAX you may set cache = false either on per-request basis or all requests basis.

I could not find similar settings in Angular http service, do you know such settings?

At the moment I have to use:

```
this.http.get(APP_DI_CONFIG.baseUri + 'appSettings.json' + '?v=' + Date.now()).map(response => response.json());
```

It is working fine. However, I am not sure if this is the most elegant way in NG2 apps?

Comment: in http you can use the headers

Comment: You can extend the Http class and make your own get method that appends date with every request and use it instead of the regular http service. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675806/how-to-extend-angular-2-http-class-in-angular-2-final