# On Access token expiration make other APIs wait before new Access token is fetched

Tags: angular, api, typescript, http

My requirement is to implement a Http post method function in which,

- If there is an API call, it should simply execute it.
- But, **if the Access token has expired AND there is an API call, the Access token API should be called first. Until it responds and the new token is acquired, the actual API should wait.**

The number of APIs calling when the access token has expired will vary. So any number of APIs should be queued.

NOTE:
Access token is declared 'expired' on client-side validation. Actual Access token expiration time will be set on the server.

How can this be achieved? A simple example will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I solved it as described here: https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-4-tutorial-handling-refresh-token-with-new-httpinterceptor/

Comment: My Angular version is 1.1.0. Will HttpInterceptor work?

Comment: Interceptors are also available in angularjs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

But this solution is based on angular 2+ if it works with angularjs in the same way, I do not know.

Comment: The website states this,
* The important thing to note here is that you must use HttpClient (which is new in Angular 4.3+) imported from @angular/common/http
* The “classic” http client does not trigger the HttpInterceptor
So, I dont think the Interceptor will detect 401 response on other APIs.

Comment: **CORRECTION:** My **Angular Version is 4.4.6**. I use Http instead of HttpClient. So HttpInterceptor cannot be used. Please suggest a way to implement the feature without HttpInterceptor.

Comment: If you use Http you need to extend the class and provide your custom implementation where you override the request part. On the other hand upgrade to Angular 6 and change to HttpClient isn't that hard. To extend Http class take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675806/how-to-extend-angular-2-http-class-in-angular-2-final

Answer (score 0):

Please find the sample implementation

```
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.sharedAPIProvider = this.inj.get(SharedAPIProvider);


    this.assetupdateArry = { users : 'getUserById' };
    return new Observable<HttpEvent<any>>((subscriber) => {

      // first try for the request
      next.handle(req)
        .timeout(API_TIMEOUT)
        .subscribe(
        (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            // console.log('success from interceptr');
                  subscriber.next(event);
            subscriber.complete();
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {

            const requestUrl = this.checkUrl(error, sessionAvoidUrls); 
            if (requestUrl && error.status === 401) {
              console.log('401 error, trying to re-login');

              // If more then 10 retry cancel request
              if (this.loginApiRetry > RE_AUTH_COUNT) {
                this.loginApiRetry = 0;
                subscriber.error(error);
              } else {
                this.loginApiRetry = this.loginApiRetry + 1;
                this.resetLoginAPICount();
                // console.log(this.loginApiRetry);
                // try to re-log the user
                this.sharedAPIProvider.reLogin().then((loginResp: any) => {
                  // re-login successful -> create new headers with the new auth token
                  if (loginResp !== undefined) {
                    this.events.publish('loginuser:update', loginResp);
                    const authToken = loginResp.response.authToken;
                    const newRequest = req.clone({
                      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', authToken),
                    });
                    this.storageProvider.set('authToken', authToken);

                    // retry the request with the new token
                    next.handle(newRequest)
                      .timeout(API_TIMEOUT)
                      .subscribe(
                      (newEvent) => {
                        if (newEvent instanceof HttpResponse) {
                          // the second try went well and we have valid response
                          // give response to user and complete the subscription
                          subscriber.next(newEvent);
                          subscriber.complete();
                        }
                      },
                      (newError) => {
                        // second try went wrong -> throw error to subscriber
                        subscriber.error(newError);
                      });
                  } else {
                    this.events.publish('user:relogin');
                  }
                });
              }
            }  else {
              subscriber.error(error);
            }
          } else {
            // the error was not related to auth token -> throw error to subscriber
            subscriber.error(error);
          }
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Rahul, My Angular version is 1.1.0. I dont think HttpInterceptor will not be triggered.

Comment: Ok Kaushik this example is for angular5. Even in angular 1 intercepter we can implement I will update on same

Comment: Ok Rahul. Thank you.